# How to convert JSON

Tags: json, highcharts, data-transform

I have the following JSON data structure:

```
var data = <%=request.getAttribute("jsondata")%>;
```

And that is my `data`:

```
[
    {
        "name": "User I/O"
    },
    {
        "key": "61410583140000"
    },
    {
        "value": "125"
    },
    {
        "name": "User I/O"
    },
    {
        "key": "61410583200000"
    },
    {
        "value": "184"
    },
    ...
]
```

Now I want to have something like:

```
[ 
   //Squared brackets!!
   [key,value]  
   [key,value]
   [key,value]
]
```

What would be the correct code for the conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you want - 
**EDIT:** Removed unnecessary filter, reduce is taking care of ignoring "name" entries.

```
data.reduce(function(a,b){ 
                if (b.key) { 
                    a.push(b.key);
                } 
                else if (b.value){
                        var key = a.pop(); 
                        a.push([key, b.value]);
                }
                return a;
            }, []);
```

This will return an array like this -

```
[[61410583140000,125],[61410583200000,184]]
```

Comment: Im getting "Syntax error on token ">", delete this token" :/

Comment: I updated the code, please try now. The reason for that error is that I was using the [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which is not supported across browsers. Anyways it was redundant here.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var result = [];
    for(var i in json_data)
        result.push([i, json_data [i]]);
```

This should work perfectly fine

Comment: It makes something like [ [0,Object], [1,Object], [2, Object]]; But how can I get something like[ [Object,Object], [Object,Object], [Object, Object]]; ?